# Why is Jetty looking for a JSP instead of a GSP?

Tags: grails, jetty, spring-webflow

I'm testing out my Grails app in Jetty (v.7.0.2).  I've created the WAR (grails prod war), and added it to the webapps directory for Jetty.  I've removed the "root" folder that was in there.  After bringing up my browser, I'm clicking on various links to make sure I can see all of the appropriate pages.  However, when I get to the link that starts a [webflow](http://www.grails.org/WebFlow), I get an error:

> Problem accessing /testapp/WEB-INF/grails-app/views//foo/start/beginHere.jsp. Reason:
>      Not found.

I've got a controller, called FooController, with a webflow named startFlow.  The first action that is run is beginHere.  I've tested this by running Grails via the command line, so I've seen this work.

Could the double slash be causing a problem?  If so, how do I fix that?  Why is it looking for a JSP file instead of a GSP?

Comment: I don't know the real problem, but Grails looks for a GSP first and if it doesn't find it looks for a JSP. The final error message is a little confusing, but the real issue is that it's looking for a GSP that's not there, or it's looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Exactly.  Basically, it would try and find `...//foo/start/beginHere.gsp` first, not find it, then try for the JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.  It turns out that its an issue with Jetty, and how it handles double slashes in the URL ([JETTY-386](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-386)).  The reason it works in Tomcat is because Tomcat handles them the way I was expecting them.

Now its just a matter of setting the configuration appropriately...

Comment: Thanks for providing your answer, it's good info for the rest of us.